# angular js - creating custom services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started learning angularjs in w3schools tutorials. Below was an example that was given to write your custom services

```
app.service('hexafy', function() {
    this.myFunc = function (x) {
        return x.toString(16);
    }
});


app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
    $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(255);
});
```

Why doesn't the below work -

```
app.service('hexafy', function(x) {
        return x.toString(16);
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.hex = hexafy(255);
});
```

Here I am letting the function accept an argument and processing it without creating a new function within it. But this approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's just the way AnglarJS works. Using `.service()`, you must pass a function that will be used to instantiate a new object. Here, that's not what you do, therefore, it does not work. BTW, w3schools is quite a weird place to start with AngularJS, you will probably find some better tutorials on the official website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , @sjahan!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service is supposed to be *instantiatable* function, so Angular creates instance of the service for you, like a constructor function. If you just want to register a function to call without constructing an instance use value:

```
app.value('hexafy', function(x) {
  return x.toString(16);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @dfsq

Comment: what is an instantiable function? Why is function(x)  that I had given in my post not instantiable?

Comment: I mean constructor functions. Then you use function as a constructor it returns an instance object. If you use service, Angular will expect function you provide to return an object which will be used as service instance. When you write `service('xxx', function (x) { return x.toString(16) })` result of such construction will not be a function, it will an empty object. That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need a method are a value to access the service class, It is better to keep a method for your need, I believe below is the code which is required for your need.

```
app.service('hexafy', function() {
        this.toString = function(x){
        return x.toString(16);
        }
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, hexafy) {
  $scope.hex = hexafy.toString(255);
});
```

or you can access it as the value just like the above answer.